# engine squeak when I start it in the morning.

Tags: honda

My 2004 Honda Accord squeaks when I start it in the morning.  I replaced the belt and it still squeaks. It is getting worst. When I turn the stearing on Idle it is now squeaking.
Also on Idle when I press the Accelarator the squeaking gets louder.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the tensioner it bad, that's the spring loaded pulley you released to change the belt with. They get weak over time and don't hold the belt as tightly anymore.

Comment: Larry Thank you for your answer. I also changed the Tensioner when I changed the belt, and the noise is the same...

Comment: @Sherry Are you absolulty sure the new belt was the exact size as the old one? Sometimes there are several belts listed and the parts store may have given you the wrong one. A belt that is a little longer will fit but will not allow the proper tension. Does the tensioner look like it's sitting in the right place, some have hash marks to let you know if the belt tensioned correctly

Answer (score 1):

Could be a pulley stopping too. An idler locking up from a bad bearing, or an accessory like steering pump or ac compressor are common as well.